# multiple vector access vs local object

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, stdvector

Knowing that the class CCPoint has only two float member variables, is there any performance benefit to use the first example over the second one?

> ```
> std::vector<p2t::Point*> polyline;
> for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
>     CCPoint p = points.at(i);
>     polyline.push_back(new p2t::Point(p.x, p.y));
> }
> ```

Put in other words, in this case, is this a good practice to use a local instance?

> ```
> std::vector<p2t::Point*> polyline;
> for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i)
>     polyline.push_back(new p2t::Point(points.at(i).x, points.at(i).y));
> ```

Thanks!

Comment: Just add a copy constructor to `Point` and do `polyline.push_back(new p2t::Point(points.at(i)));`. One call to `at` and only one copy is performed.

Comment: Just profile it and see. The only real way to answer performance questions like this.

Comment: Does the first version copy-construct?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: That would be a converting constructor, not a copy constructor.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oops. How obvious ;)

Comment: Nope. No "copy-constructor" for p2t::Point. ;)

Comment: Do you really need pointers and `new`? That's likely to take far, far longer than accessing a vector element, even if you do use `at` rather than `[]`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes I need pointers. [p2t](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) expects an array of p2t::Point pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would write that:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<p2t::Point>> polyline;
for (const CCPoint& p : points)
    polyline.push_back(std::unique_ptr<p2t::Point>(new p2t::Point(p.x, p.y)));
```

Note use of a reference saves doing the lookup twice, but without copying the point.  `unique_ptr` ensures the memory is later freed correctly with `delete`, you no longer need to do that yourself.  And the range-based for creates shorter more readable code, and also avoids the redundant range-checking inside `at()`.

In C++14 it gets even more efficient:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<p2t::Point>> polyline;
for (const CCPoint& p : points)
    polyline.emplace_back(std::make_unique<p2t::Point>(p.x, p.y));
```

Note that storing points by pointer is not ideal from a performance perspective.  That's something you usually do when you want a polymorphic collection.  Does `p2t::Point` have virtual member functions?

Comment: I get a 'No matching member function for call 'push_back' when I use the first unique_ptr version. But using a range-based for with reference is very elegant! I'll go with:    std::vector<p2t::Point*> polyline;
    for (const CCPoint& p : points)
        polyline.push_back(new p2t::Point(p.x, p.y));

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur: Sorry, I forget that `unique_ptr` has an explicit constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Never do optimizations before you've determined that this part of your code is really slowing down your application. The example with a local variable is better for understanding, so always use it in a first implementation. Anyway, compiler will probably generate the same code for the both in Release mode.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably going to be a minor gain from not doing the lookup twice. Notice that you call `at` twice in the second example, but only once in the first.

Answer (score 1):

With the modern compiler, it doesn't matter, it will generate the same code for both if optimization is on. To check that, you can turn on the compiler option /FA to generate the assembly code, if there're same, it means the compiler will take care of this.